# Safari 17.0 clear history command deletes passwords in keychains

Tags: safari, security, password, keychain

Since the Safari 17.0 update under Ventura 13.6,  I noticed a problem with the "Clear history" menu command. When clearing history with the "all history" option, Safari asks for a keychain password (I use several keychains other than the session one which is locked by default).
Whether I enter the keychain password or not, Safari randomly deletes a website password from one of the keychains each time the history is cleared.

Fortunately, I make regular copies of my keychains.
Moving keychains to a subfolder also prevents them from being modified by Safari.

The problem occurs on my two different machines.
The Safari 17.0 update appears to be causing the issue although it was followed immediately by the 13.6 security update. Perhaps should it be looked around also?

Is anyone else experiencing the same problem?

Notes:

- macOS Ventura 13.6
- MacBook Pro (MacBookPro13 2018 Thunderbolt 3) & MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
- Safari Version 17.0
- iCloud *not* used to sync the keychain

Answer (score 0):

On my MacBook air M1, installing the new Ventura 13.6.1 update from the offline archive (AppStore) reinstalls Safari 16.6 and solves the problem. Curiously, the same procedure on my Intel MacBook Pro installs Safari 17.1. Here too, the problem seems to have been corrected.